# How to update a specific field in an array that matches a query in a Mongodb document?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have a document that looks like this:

```json
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f55fdede873f132ec09207e"), 
    "edition_id" : NumberInt(35889464), 
    "title" : "TEAM ROCKET EDITION", 
    "date" : "2020-09-19T10:00:00.000+0000", 
    "homescreen" : {
        "image" : "https://media3.giphy.com/media/oOfLwhLyRUoRW/giphy.gif", 
        "song" : "5T8l7ciAo4H3NGFld8c9Ow"
    }, 
    "teams" : [
        {
            "team_id" : "8675309", 
            "team_name" : "", 
            "team_code" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "team_id" : "7779311", 
            "team_name" : "", 
            "team_code" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "team_id" : "79369254", 
            "team_name" : "", 
            "team_code" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to form a MongoDB query that will find a matching `team_id` and update the `team_name` for that array item. I've tried several things within this structure:

```react
import { connectToDatabase } from 'utils/mongodb';

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
  const {
    query: { edition_id, team_name, team_id },
  } = req;

  console.log({ req });

  const edition = await db.collection('editions').findOneAndUpdate(
    { edition_id: parseInt(edition_id) },
    {
      $set: {

      },
    },
  );
  res.json(edition);
};
```

but I can't seem to formulate the right query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this query,

```
  const edition = await db.collection('editions').updateOne(
    { 'teams.team_id': '8675309' },
    {
      $set: {
          'teams.$.team_name': 'team_name_value'
      },
    },
  );
```

Comment: That worked! However, I need it to match the `edition_id` as well, since the same `team_id` will exist in multiple documents . . .